# Child domain new cert request - certificate template permissions do not allow current user to enroll 0x80094012

Tags: active-directory, ad-certificate-services, pki

I have the following AD configuration:

rootca (standalone not domain connected)

- mydom.local

  - dc1.mydom.local
  - svr1.mydom.local
  - subca.mydom.local(enterprise subordinate CA)
  - other.mydom.local

    - dc1.other.mydom.local
    - svr1.other.mydom.local

I can register webserver certificates OK for svr1.mydom.local, however I log into svr1.other.mydom.local with the child domain administrator and I get the following error:

`Permissions on the certificate template do not allow the current user to enroll for this type of certificate (0x80094012)`

I think this must related to permissions however I am not sure how to proceed - what is the best practice to allow child domain administrators to request certificates from the subordinate CA located in the parent domain?

My inf file is below:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject="CN=svr1.other.mydom.local"
Exportable=TRUE
KeyLength=2048
KeySpec=1
MachineKeySet=TRUE
[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 ; Server Authentication
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 ; Client Authentication
[RequestAttributes]
CertificateTemplate = WebServer
```

and i am running the following commands on `svr1.other.mydom.local` as `administrator@other.mydom.local` below:

```
certreq -new c:\svr1.inf c:\svr1.req
certreq -submit c:\svr1.req c:\svr1.cer ; I get the error here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the user a member of a security group that has Read and Enroll permission on the certificate template?  That is required.

**Administering Certificate Templates**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725621%28v=ws.10%29

When you install certificates into the computer store and use auto-enrollment or manually request the certificate using the Certificates snap-in, the requesting *computer* account needs Read and Enroll permissions on the certificate template.

However, when you're using Certreq.exe to request certificates, even if they are computer certificates and use MachineKeySet = True, the requesting *user* needs Read and Enroll permissions on the certificate template.  When you use Certreq.exe, the computer permissions are not used.

Comment: thanks, the user requesting is the child domain administrator, looking at template permissions I see enterprise and domain admins, is it acceptable/good-practice to add the child domain admin group to these permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good-practice scenario.  Seems like the only option for someone to use a template to enroll a cert is to have permission to do so.  It's not as if you have another choice for where the templates are located or which template location to use.